# Android multiple tabs view how to know if one is selected

Tags: android, events, tabs

the title explains it all
i want if the user chooses another tab then the old tap clear some texts but i don't know how to reach that event, i created the tabs using this code

```
 th = (TabHost) findViewById(R.id.tabhost); 
         th.setup();
          spec=th.newTabSpec("tag1");
         spec.setContent(R.id.tab1);
         spec.setIndicator("tap1");
         th.addTab(spec);        
         spec=th.newTabSpec("tag2");
         spec.setContent(R.id.tab2);
         spec.setIndicator("tap2");                 
         th.addTab(spec);
         th.setCurrentTab(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Register a `TabHost.OnTabChangeListener`:

```
tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener( new TabHost.OnTabChangeListener{

    public void onTabChanged(String tabId){
        // do something here
    }
})
```